# Python Pandas - "None of [' '] are in the columns"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, append

I have this code which selects a column of the csv file, transposes it and appends to one big csv file:

```
def append_pandas(s,d):
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(d, sep=';')
    df_add = pd.read_csv(s, sep=';')
    def append_a_row(df, df_add):
        df_add = df_add.set_index('Well ID').T
        df_add.insert(0, 'Time Point', len(df) + 1)
        return df.append(df_add)
    df_new = append_a_row(df, df_add)
    df_new.to_csv(d, sep=';', index=False)
```

When working trying it out with a file, it gives me this error:

```
"None of ['Well ID'] are in the columns"
```

I already saw the suggested answer related to potential whitespaces and tried using `delim_whitespace=True` but it did not solve the problem.

The datasets look like this:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas? :(

Comment: The problem arises at `df_add.set_index('Well ID')`, clearly `Well ID` is not among the column names of the `df_add` dataframe. Can you read the file outsite the function and print out its columns (e.g. `print(df_add.columns)`)?

Comment: Maybe you need to switch `s` and `d`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you read the file outside the function and print out its columns:

```
print(df_add.columns)
```

It's possible that your column have some more extra spaces, like 'Well ID   '

Change the column name:

```
df_add.rename(columns = {'bad_acutal_name':'Well ID'}, inplace = True)
```